# xml transformation using jboss

Tags: java, jboss

```
  <bean class="ats.emvo.transform.TransformXml" id="trsnformbean"/>
<camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="_route1">
        <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/in"/>
        <to id="_to2" uri="file:///E:/out"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

> i want to Transform XMl to another xml format. assume i have a logic in ats.emvo.transform.TransformXml java file how do i integrated to transform tis in camel context input (file:///d:/in) is xml file and i want to save it as another location as xml. i already add this file as bean class to camel

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your bean directly in your routing logic. Just make sure your bean is correctly referenced. With Spring XML, the syntax looks like this:

```
<route id="_route1">
    <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/in"/>
    <bean ref="myBeanName" method="doTransform"/>
    <to id="_to2" uri="file:///E:/out"/>
 </route>
```

You may also want to check the Apache Camel documentation on the matter:
http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html

Comment: its blueprint project